# Architecturally replace singleton main object with IoC Container

Tags: c#, architecture, ioc-container

My question is about software architecture in general.

Let's consider an example:

We have a Windows Service application.

Program.cs creates and starts an instance of `MainService` class.

`MainService` inherits from `ServiceBase` therefore implements `OnStart(string[] args)` method.

Usually, when I design my application, I would do something like this in `OnStart` method:

```
MainSingletonObject.Initialize();
```

Initialize would read the config data from app.config and create an instances of required classes, open WCF hosts (if any), etc.

Is this a good practice to start a service application? What would be your personal architectural advice to improve the design? Where to fit an IoC container and why would I need it if I am doing a dependency injection by hand fine.

Comment: I see two problems with it: 1) you're using the singleton antipattern ( http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/ ), and 2) it serves no purpose. Software architecture isn't about stacking patterns on top of each others, it is about structuring a program in a way that makes it easy to develop, understand and maintain. Anything that doesn't contribute to one of these has no place in your architecture. So what do you gain by creating such a singleton, over a regular class, or even a function?

Comment: I get the clean code. Instead of having to call var myMainClass = new MainClass(); and myMainClass.Start(); I have only one line of code in service OnStart method. What advantage would it be to simply create an object and run a method?

Comment: But you may be right, I lose and ability to pass parameters to a constructor. I could simply be reading all the dependencies from app.config in OnStart method, and, if there would be a problem, indicate that the start of the service has failed.

Comment: The advantage would be simpler code. You could still have just one line of code in `OnStart` if you feel that's important. (Just make it call `RunMain()`, or `new MyApp().Run()`, for example (and both of these can take parameters just as well as your singleton `Initialize()`). And then you can delete all the error-prone, untestable and fragile singleton code, which serves no purpose any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the IoC in the service bootstrap phase here:

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                { 
                    new ServiceClass() 
                };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Instead of having `new ServiceClass`, I would resolve the service class via IoC.  So you avoid having an IoC dependency in the service implementation. If you need to construct via injection a brand new object from inside your implementation consider exposing a service `ITypeFactory` registered in the IoC that insulates your code from the particular container you will use.  In general, you can measure a good design in IoC if you insulate the container too.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton must not depend on others to initialise it. It is initialised as soon as it is used.

This is how I would do it:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static readonly MySingleton _instance = new MySingleton();

    private MySingleton()
    {
        // ... read config
    }

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

Here `static readonly` makes sure this is **lazy load**.